# Get Drive's Information and Sort

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How can I get drive's information and sort them with `AvalableFreeSpace`? Here's my code:

```
List<DriveInfo> list = new List<DriveInfo>();

foreach (DriveInfo item in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    list.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to check `IsReady` property prior to using it else it may throw an exception. then you can use `OrderBy` to sort the sequence.

```
var sortedDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                            .Where(x=> x.IsReady)
                            .OrderBy(x=> x.AvailableFreeSpace)
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't get it how should i check ? before assigning in sorted drives or when im printing them? i get is ready exception

Comment: Also note that when drive is not ready am ignoring the drives which are not ready

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ `OrderBy` - Sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order according to a key. (MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)

```
var sortedDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives().OrderBy(l => l.AvailableFreeSpace).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using LinQ you can sort it like this. Checking the `IsReady` will prevent exceptions.

```
var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                      .Where(x => x.IsReady)
                      .OrderBy(x => x.AvailableFreeSpace)
                      .ToList();
```